# Is there something I'm missing in this AS3 code that's wrong or is there something potentially wrong with the project file/primary class file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Just a disclaimer I'm very much a beginner with coding, been taught basics but there's most likely a much better way to achieve the same result, however this is the method I've been told to work with.

The Error itself is:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at Target/gameLoop()

Code for 'Target' Class file:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

public class Target extends MovieClip {
    
    var DRef:MovieClip;
    
    var TargState:String = "Idle";

    public function Target() {
        // constructor code
        
        
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,gameLoop);
    }
    
    function gameLoop(myEvent:Event)
    {
        if(TargState == "Idle")
        {
                             /*THIS APPEARS TO BE THE ISSUE, 
                             HOWEVER IT HAS WORKED FOR EVERY 
                             OTHER PROJECT SO FAR*/
            if(this.hitTestObject(DRef.det1))
            {
                //TargState = "Dead";
                trace("COLLIDING")
            }
        }
        
        if(TargState == "Dead")
        {
            trace("Target: Dead")
        }
    }

}
```

}

Code for 'Detonator' Class file:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

public class Detonator extends MovieClip {
    
    var DRef:MovieClip;
    
    var DetState:String = "Idle"
    var frameCount:Number = 0
    var SecMonitor:Number = 0
    var DetTimer:Number = 10
    var GOtimer:Number = 14

    public function Detonator() {
        // constructor code
        
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,gameLoop);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDown);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUp);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,kDown);
        
        DRef = MovieClip(this.parent);
    }
    
    function gameLoop(myEvent:Event)
    {
        
        
        
        if(DetState == "DetOn")
        {
            trace("Det: Armed")
            
            frameCount += 1;
        
            if(frameCount > 24)
            {
                frameCount = 0;
                SecMonitor += 1;
                DetTimer -= 1;
                GOtimer -= 1;
            }
            
            if(DetTimer < 0)
            {
                DetTimer = 0;
                DetState = "explode";
            }
        }
        
        if(DetState == "explode")
        {
            trace("Det: BOOM")
            
            this.height += 5;
            this.width += 5;
            this.alpha -= 0.05;
            
            if(this.width > 120)
            {
                this.width = 120;
            }
            
            if(this.height > 120)
            {
                this.height = 120;
            }
            
            if(this.alpha < 0)
            {
                
                DetState = "Dead";
            }
        }
        
        if(DetState == "Dead")
        {
            trace("Det: Dead")
        }
        
        
        countDownBox.text = DetTimer.toString();
        //trace(GOtimer)
        //trace(DetTimer)
        //trace(frameCount)
    }
    
    function mDown(myEvent:MouseEvent)
    {
        if(DetState == "DetOn")
        {
            this.startDrag();
        }
    } 
    
    function mUp(myEvent:MouseEvent)
    {
        if(DetState == "DetOn")
        {
            this.stopDrag();
        }
    }
    
    function kDown(myEvent:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if(DetState == "Idle")
        {
            if(myEvent.keyCode == 32)
            {
                DetState = "DetOn";
            }
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    

}
```

}

So I've been given mostly dormant and barren files to work with for a game project due this Thursday and can't seem to use the only method I've been taught to reference class files. I thought the problem might lie in the fact that it's a movieclip type variable and therefore 'doesn't know' what to do with it. However I've asked for a second opinion from peers and no one (including myself) knows why this refuses to work.

At the moment I understand that the class file would only have to be referenced if the object I'm trying to test 'collision' on called 'det1' has linkage, but it does, therefore I figure that would be the best course of action HOWEVER, I also tested it without the class file reference (The 'DRef' before '.det1') and I get another error telling me: "E:\Education\Work\UAL\BA Games Design\Year 1\C&D\Units\PU001546\Part 1\DemolisionV6Started\Target.as, Line 25, Column 27 1120: Access of undefined property det1." So even though I know and have checked that object is dynamic, a movieclip and has been named 'det1' it seems to still think it is an undefined property.

Quite frankly I have no idea what to do next as this method is fundamental to making the game function as the Game Design Document I've been given says it should. I've even tried downloading the same files fresh with none of my code and I get the same type of error but it's:

## 1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Stage@7fffd13e0d1 to flash.display.MovieClip. at Main()

I assume that is an issue with this 'declaration'(?) mRef = MovieClip(this.parent); even though that works fine in other projects

Answer (score 0):

1- In the first class you should instantiate the object before you use it.
DRef= new MovieClip()

2- In the second one MovieClip constructor takes no arguments so it should be
DRef = new MovieClip() not DRef = new MovieClip(this.parent);

if DRef construct takes arguments then you you should use DRef = new YOUCustomeClass(arguments);